# highstocks align ticks cross multiple charts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to reinvent the wheel apparently >.>

But issues I'm having is lining up the two axis,

Any help with lining up the multiple charts would be appreciated, I'm drawing a blank.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ah8p3581/1/

```
Please Follow Link - http://jsfiddle.net/ah8p3581/1/
```

Comment: It's caused by using different types of series - OHLC created extra gap AND by different granularity of series. The second issue can be avoided by disabling dataGrouping (or setting to be the same for the second chart) : http://jsfiddle.net/ah8p3581/4/

Comment: I tried your idea of setting the same datagrouping option to both charts (kinda need it for this amount of data), yet the issue returned *Cough* any more advice, kind sir?

http://jsfiddle.net/ah8p3581/5/

Comment: sacrificing a perfectly straight line comparison, by utilising the original charts axis position translation both charts make a line which without care inspection appears to be directly straight, yet most importantly the axis values matchup.
Guessing this is the best I can pull off at present http://jsfiddle.net/ah8p3581/6/
Thanks for the insight and the fresh pair of eyes Pawel